# Storing a list with React Native AsyncStorage: many keys or one?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I want to store a list of items with AsyncStorage. The list will be updated over time.

Here is an example of a state the list can be in:

```
[
  { 
    name: "Alice", 
    email: "alice@example.com"
  }, 
  {
    name: "Bob", 
    email: "bob@example.com", 
    address: "30 Madison Ave., NY"
  }
]
```

Now, it seems that there are two options for storing this list:

1. Store each contact under its own key
2. Store the whole list under one key

There are advantages to either approach - what is preferred in React Native?

Comment: Consider using a database library like [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/). It has many advantages over AsyncStorage for data more complex than key/value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this depends on how you plan to use, access, and update the data. There are several asyncstorage methods you can use to help make either case easier.

If you decide to go the many keys route, have a look at [multiSet](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#multiset) and [multiGet](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#multiget), which allows you to retrieve several keys in a single function call. And [getAllKeys](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#getallkeys) will save you the trouble of "keep[ing] track of all the keys you created", solving both of the problems mentioned by Fredrick Motte.

For updating many keys in one call, check out [multiMerge](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#multimerge) which is a really powerful method, similar to [mergeItem](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#mergeitem) but multiple keys at once.

So, you see you can really go either route. If you divide your data up into multiple keys, then you'll probably just want to spend some time getting familiar with the methods I mentioned above.

And David's suggestion to give Relm a look might have some value for you as well, again... depending on your need.

Comment: Does AsyncStorage is capable of storing large amount of Masterdata ?

If i Stringify a JSON object and store it as value in Asyncstorage, What's limit for value with key in AsyncStorage

Answer (score 3):

For ease of use I'd store the list as a whole; since then you don't have to keep track of all the keys you created for each contact individually; and loading/saving them will be easier (just one function call instead of looping over all of your contacts).

But this is mostly a personal preference; there are no real constraints for any of the two methods.

Comment: @Chris Geirman

Does AsyncStorage is capable of storing large amount of Masterdata ?

If i Stringify a JSON object and store it as value in Asyncstorage, What's limit for value with key in AsyncStorage

Comment: @MayurBaldha there are limits and I did some research around this back in April 2015. Things may have changed since, but I pulled up my notes for you and this was the situation at that time... 10MB Limit on Android Chrome 40, 2MB Android 4.3, 5MB iOS

Comment: @ChrisGeirman : at a time in one key value pair. what's maximum length (no of characters) allowed to store as value with key considering these limitations you said?

Answer (score 3):

I would add to the two good answers from Chris and Frederick:
it depends on the size of your list, and the size of your documents.

Going with one list as a whole is much easier to manage, but does not scale (computation will get heavier with the size of your global value).
going with one key per item adds some complexity but scales.

Personally I started with everything in one key, and now am refactoring to have one document per key, because when I'm processing hundreds of big documents, performances clearly degrade.

And if you are handling thousands or 10s of thousands of elements, I think you should go for a proper database like sqlite or realm (but debugging is an issue at the moment in realm).

Would be interested to know the true limits of asyncStorage, I read somewhere, it was a few megabytes unless you ask in your native config to increase it